# glTF Import Changes Material Names

Tags: import, gltf

I've been running into an issue that whenever I import a glb/gltf it will change the name of my materials to "Image_0" and incrementally change the number for each different material file. This issue then transfers over to when I export my file, it will always export with the "Image_x" name and overwrite any other materials that may be part of my files with other models. Is there a way to fix this? or to ensure it retains the original material name on import? I attempted to rename them manually but I get an error when I export the file and the export fails.

(If it's helpful, the gltf/glb was generated by the Substance Painter "glTF PBR Metal Roughness" export)